# Is </applet> necessary to write in comments in java file despite the fact that <applet> is an empty tag?

Tags: java, applet

While writing  tag in java file as comments, does it need a closing tag? (Since  tag is an empty tag) but it does not open appletviewer when i give the command in cmd.. However, it works when i put  at the end ..why?
e.g.

```
    // <applet code="radiobutton.class" height=500 width=500>
    // </applet>


    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.applet.*;
    public class radiobutton extends Applet implements ItemListener 
    {
        Button bt;......
```

It works when I do the above!!

BUT NOT when I do:

```
    // <applet code="radiobutton.class" height=500 width=500 />


    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.applet.*;
    public class radiobutton extends Applet implements ItemListener 
    {
        Button bt;.......
```

Answer (score 0):

A singleton `applet`tag as you showed is XHTML only. The applet tag is not a pure singleton; you may add `param` tags to add parameters.

So without ending tag, the appletviewer would have to parse the entire source after `<aplet ...>` and evidently the XHTML form `<applet .../>` it does not understand.